# Is this an acceptable practice or convention of parenthesis use?

Tags: javascript, canvas, convention

```
    return (zS.value*0.1).toPrecision(3);
```

I'm curious if wrapping parenthesis around this return statement follows best practices or if there is a more correct way, such as making the zS.value*0.1 a variable. Does it even matter?

Comment: Doesn't really matter.

Comment: I would say try not to do alot on a single line.. you will be safe guarding yourself from future maintainance hell and also help others new to ur code.

Comment: you can put "Number" in front of the paren to improve readability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

If it works, it works. Since you are calling `toPrecision()` on the result of `zS.value * 0.1`, then yeah, parentheses are good.

**Opinion:**

In the grand scheme of things your style is your choice unless you work somewhere where style and conventions are dictated or agreed upon by the team (let's ignore for a minute the argument of whether writing hard-to-read code provides some measure of job security). I prefer to create a simple variable and return that. For example, I would have written this as:

```
var x = (zS.value * 0.1);
var retVal = x.toPrecision(3);
return retVal;
```

One reason for this is readability and maintainability. Another is that it is easy to add a watch for `retVal` when debugging.